# How do I attach a propeller to this motor?

Tags: propellers, motor, building

As many of you already know, I am getting into RC planes. I went to my hobby shop today and bought a motor and some props, but I can't figure out how to attach a propeller to the motor. Unlike what I've seen on YouTube videos, there is no shaft on the front of the motor. The motor is a Dualsky 2304c 1850kv brushless motor.

Apologies for bad pictures, I only have my laptop with me.

The front of the motor:

[image]

The back of the motor:

[image]

The motor accessories:

[image]

The propeller and accessories:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use one of the provided rubber rings to attach the propeller to the motor. The 2 protruding screws with their heads are the anchor points for the rubber before it is wrapped over the prop to the other screw.
The propeller motor connection is not rigid but has a little give and comes loose on impact, hopefully saving the propeller and the motor that way.

Comment: I won't upvote just yet as I can't test it right now. I've heard people talk about 'propsavers', is this one of those?

Comment: Yes, it is called a prop saver. Your motor has it already built-in in contrast to having it added to the shaft as a separate part.

Comment: Also, those plastic rings fit in the rear of the prop. Pick the one that fits the boss on the motor. Add a drop of glue because they can fall out if you crash hard enough to break the O-ring, and they're easy to lose.

Comment: Yes, I managed to figure out what the plastic rings were for. But I didn't think of gluing them.